# Intranet running on IIS 8.5 with only Windows Authentication enabled returns 402.1 and then 403 error

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-8.5, windows-authentication

WE've got an ASP.Net MVC application running on an internal server. We are using only Windows Authentication to allow access to portions of the site.
When we set IIS to require an SSL connection (using internally generated cert) we always get a 403 response.

If I turn off the SSL Required switch everything works correctly. But as soon as I turn it on the 403 error is back on.

1. Is this the way it is suppose to work?
2. Is there a workaround?
3. Is it related to the self generated cert?

**Updated Info**
The initial error is a 402.1 error that then gets routed to to 403.14 error message.

Comment: please add the 403 sub-code to your question, check the IIS logs for it.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly specify `https://` in the address bar, or enable some form of HTTP to HTTPS redirection, preferably through URL REWRITE MODULE for IIS

Comment: Explicitly using https://myserver/ doesn't work. That is when I get the 403 error.

Comment: When you required SSL, how did you configure the client certificate portion?

Comment: Client Cert was configured to accept any

Comment: Also tried setting the Client Cert to ignore